# Implementing a customized desktop application using C# and.NET 4.7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, desktop-application, startmenu, .net-4.7

How to customize the properties of the startmenu shortcut desktop application implemented in C# and .NET 4.7?

I had created desktop application shortcut using IWshRuntimeLibrary,WshShell,IWshShortcut and the application name as exe1.I was stuck on customizing the properties such as start,run as administrator,open file location to option1 and option2.
**How may the application be customized?**

Here is the C# code for shortcut desktop application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

namespace Shortcut2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            IWshShortcut exe1 = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(@"C:\Users\DIVYASRI\Start\exe1.lnk");
            exe1.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
            exe1.Description = "Launch the App";
            exe1.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing some sort of Installer yourself?

Comment: @Ralf Not an installler.Actually this is a task i got from my team lead.When we are searching for an application in search bar it should shown option1 and option2 instead of showing start ,run as administrator,open file location.